# Unable to init from given url while reading S3 image through Cloudfront

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I have Laravel backend with [Intervention package](https://image.intervention.io/) to handle images.
All images are stored in S3 bucket and are accessed through CDN - Cloudfront distribution.

When user requests image from my app I use something like this line to fetch image and return it to user.

```
 return Image::make("https://*********.cloudfront.net/S3_image_path_and_filename.jpg")->response()->header('Cache-Control', 'max_age=3600');
```

This code worked without any troubles for more than a year without any changes but recently I started to see that some images on client side are empty and there are errors saying

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException Unable to init from given url
```

I looked up for issues with missing images but they exist in S3 bucket and are accessible through Cloudfront. I even see them on client side after clearing cache or waiting for some time - so this issue is flacky, can't reproduce it. I even don't see any error associated with images in Cloudfront distribution.

My questions are

1. what could be the reasons behind this issue?
2. how I can debug it?
3. maybe I need to handle the exception above but I am not sure what should be returned to user in that case?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364200/unable-to-init-from-given-url-in-intervention-image-2-3) question seems to imply a simple retry might work. You might be tripping some DDoS protection on cloudfront that rejects some of your requests.

Comment: thank you, saw this workaround. would like also to understand the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see a decent way to debug this easily. [the code that throws that exception](https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/master/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php#L66) seems to suppress the actual issue so that information is lost. As soon as you get an error like that you can try to do run a `file_get_contents` (with similar context) or a cURL request to see if you get an error hopefully with more detail.