# Why runing \Image::make under docker raised error?

Tags: laravel, docker

I try to run under docker  laravel 9.52.15  app with  filament 2.17.52 and intervention/image 2.7  with Dockerfile.yml having :

```
  FROM php:8.1.6-apache
     ...
  RUN pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

  RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp  --with-jpeg

  RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

and running code :

```
        try {
            \Log::info(varDump($this->bgimageFileUrl, ' -0 BannerGeneratorBuilder->generate $this->bgimageFileUrl::'));
            $this->bgImageObject = \Image::make($this->bgimageFileUrl);
        } catch (\Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException $e) {
            \Log::info(varDump($e->getMessage(), ' -1 BannerGeneratorBuilder->generate $e->getMessage()::'));
            return $this;
        }
```

image is not displayed and I see errors in log file :

```
[2023-10-21 14:36:58] production.INFO: scalar => (string) : -0 BannerGeneratorBuilder->generate $this->bgimageFileUrl:: : http://127.0.0.1:8085/storage/filament_banners_media/2/blue_light_1.png
[2023-10-21 14:36:58] production.INFO: scalar => (string) : -1 BannerGeneratorBuilder->generate $e->getMessage():: : Unable to init from given url (http://127.0.0.1:8085/storage/filament_banners_media/2/blue_light_1.png).
[2023-10-21 14:36:58] production.INFO: NULL : -10 $response:: : NULL
```

But if to copypaste image
`http://127.0.0.1:8085/storage/filament_banners_media/2/blue_light_1.png` into browser - it is rendered ok.

Under my OS kubuntu 20 it worked ok, am am sure.
The thing is that I installed kubuntu 22 with php 8.2, but this project I need to leave on php 8.1, that why I try to run it under docker...

Did I miss something in docker installation ?
Which debugging can I make in this case ?

**UPDATED BLOCK :**
I check inside of bash :

```
root@7c8739a66926:/PROJECT_ROOT#  echo "allow_url_fopen=On"
allow_url_fopen=On
```

If I understood correctly I modified in .env :

```
#APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8085
APP_URL=http://host.docker.internal:8085
```

Is it correct ?

But running urls

```
http://host.docker.internal:8085/
```

OR

```
http://host.docker.internal:8085/admin/login
```

In both cases I got DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error ?

I read this https://medium.com/@TimvanBaarsen/how-to-connect-to-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container-112b4c71bc66 article:
I have valid version

```
# docker -v
Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc
```

But still have no sure how correctly use host.docker.internal  ? Not to write it in .env file?

Comment: Can you please check if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled on your host by running `dd(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'))`? I am trying to rule out this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52128715/296555

Comment: looking at output of php info I see :
allow_url_fopen = On

Yes, I have run php artisan storage:link priorly - images which are saved under storage are shown ok on my pages.
Which certificate problem on my localhost was mentioned there ? I run it under docker.
On localhost of my kubuntu 20.04 it worked ok...

Comment: Check if you can curl or wget the image URL from within the Docker container. This will help determine if it's a networking issue. 
`docker exec -it your_container_name /bin/bash`           
`curl http://127.0.0.1:8085/storage/filament_banners_media/2/blue_light_1.png`

Answer (score 1):

Inside a Docker container, 127.0.0.1 or localhost refers to the container itself, not the host machine. This means that if you're trying to access an external URL using localhost within a Docker container, it will not find the file.
Firstly, you can try this command:

```
 RUN echo "allow_url_fopen=On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

Secondly, ensure the image and its parent directories have the right permissions.

Finally, try replacing `http://127.0.0.1:8085` with `http://host.docker.internal:8085` and see if that works.

Comment: Please read UPDATED BLOCK. Did I understand you ?

Comment: You understand correct, but this should work on Docker for Windows and Docker for Mac, but for other platforms, you might need a different approach. On Linux, for instance, you can check your machine's local IP address (Docker container IP) and use that instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Yes, I work under Kubuntu 22.04. Please a bit more details

Comment: First, list all running containers with their container IDs: `docker ps`. Then get container (where you run your Laravel project) IP address: `docker inspect [CONTAINER_ID] | grep IPAddress`.  Now use this IP adress instead of 127.0.0.1 and check that if it's working or not.